# onclick="history.back() don't work in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

this simple line of code:

```
<a href="#" value="Go back!" onclick="history.back()" class="nav-li" >Back</a>
```

works good for Chrome and Firefox, but not for Safari and IE..., for IE it normal case, only very strange persons use it, but why Safari ?

Note: the whole project is done with django 1.45

Comment: have you tried `window.history.back()` or `history.go(-1)` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625126/window-history-go-1-not-working-in-ios-homescreen-app

Comment: back ()
iedited post so the full code line is now present

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it should be `history.go(-1)` or else it won't work.

Comment: Is there documentation as to why this is?

Comment: one extra feature discovered to be helpfull:
changing the href="#" in initial code to:
<label class="nav-li" for="back">Back</label>
<input class='Back' id = "back" type=button value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

CSS for class Back
.Back {
     display:none;
  }